# WCF Client confusion

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to connect to a WCF Service hosted as a Windows Service.

The WCF service has an endpoint at:

```
net.tcp://localhost:9164/GettingStarted/
```

I can start the service without any issue.

However, i am now trying to connect to it via my console application.

This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Step 1: Create a URI to serve as the base address.
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9164/GettingStarted/");

    // Step 2: Create a ServiceHost instance.
    ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

    try
    {
        // Step 3: Add a service endpoint.
        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new NetTcpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

        // Step 4: Enable metadata exchange.
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = false;
        smb.HttpsGetEnabled = false;
        selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Step 5: Start the service.
        selfHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");

        // Close the ServiceHost to stop the service.
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the service.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
        selfHost.Close();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
        selfHost.Abort();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I keep getting this exception:

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException

However, nothing else is connecting to the service.

Also, I could test the service via the web browser when it was http based. How do I test with net.tcp?

EDIT:

WCF Client Updated:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ChannelFactory<ICalculator> channelFactory = null;

    try
    {
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();

        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9164/GettingStarted/CalculatorService");

        channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(binding, endpointAddress);

        ICalculator channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        double result = channel.Add(4.0, 5.9);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        //Timeout error  
        if (channelFactory != null)
            channelFactory.Abort();
        throw;
    }
    catch (FaultException)
    {
        if (channelFactory != null)
            channelFactory.Abort();
        throw;
    }
    catch (CommunicationException)
    {
        //Communication error  
        if (channelFactory != null)
            channelFactory.Abort();
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (channelFactory != null)
            channelFactory.Abort();
        throw;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. Isn't the code you show for a server (with a ServiceHost) not a client. It's been a very long time since I worked with WCF, but I doubt I've forgotten that much

Comment: No? The Serverside is just a WCF Service project that references my WCF Service Library. This is a client side console project to try to connect to it.

Comment: Do you have an alternative to WCF for local area network communications? This is getting quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description,your WCF service has been hosted on Windows service.Now you want to connect to it. I don't understand what you mean by connection.Since WCF service is hosted on Windows service,you can generate a proxy class to call it according to WCF service,but I found your console Application still wants to host WCF Services. I don't know what you want to do, but if you want to host WCF Services in console application,you need to change your base address, because according to your description,you need to host WCF Services in Windows service and console application.But their addresses cannot be the same,you can change the base address in the console application,such as the following:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9166/Test/");
ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);
```

Comment: I managed to write a class to do it. However, I keep getting a System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:9164 I dont understand this. I know that my service is sitting on that port but my application is only trying to connect to it?

Comment: Also, it keeps saying I need administrator privileges to debug it? Is there any code I can put where it will let me bypass this.

Comment: But the code you provide is not to connect, but to register an endpoint again.In addition, you need administrator permission to use the port number. You can use administrator to open VS.

Comment: My apologies. I've updated the code. Is it correct now?

Comment: Does your client report "addressalreadyinuseexception" exception when running?

Comment: I realized what it was. The reason it keeps saying the addressalreadyinuse is because I need to uncheck the start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution.

Comment: You are right. The same address can only be used by one WCF service.

Comment: As I said in reply, the same base address cannot be used by two WCF Services at the same time. You can modify their base addresses.

Comment: Hi @Ding peng, is there a way to programmatically set it when installing?

Comment: I think you can catch this exception. If this address is occupied, change it to a standby address.